# Passing variables from one procedure to another

Tags: vb.net

How can I use a vairable from Sub Main, in another sub.

Example
`Sub Main() 
Dim x As Long
End Sub`

```
Sub Test() Dim y = x End Sub
```

Is this possible on vb.net

Comment: Declare x as a global variable?

Comment: it isn't possible if variables defined in Procedure-level scope. See [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: How is this done on vb.net? and would calling it be the same as say if it was in the same procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it to a function and return it again:

```
Sub Main()
Dim x As Long
' Give x a value
x = Test(x)
' Do something else with x
End Sub

Function Test(x As Long) As Long
' Do something with x
Return x
End Sub
```

Or declare it as a global variable:

```
Dim x As Long
Sub Main()
' Do something with x
End Sub

Sub Test()
Dim y = x ' Do something else
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for your first answer.  The 2nd answer will technically work, but it is horrible programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to do this.

Declare the value out of all the Subs on the top.

```
Public Class Form 1
        Dim x As Long

    Private Sub Main ()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Test ()

    End Sub    
End Class
```

And then write `y = x` on whichever Sub you want!